# Is it possible to return a bool from a unittest.TestCase?

Tags: python-3.x, unit-testing

I'm looking to log the results of testing in an excel file. This is my expected output

```
test, True, 2018/11/27    OR    test, False, 2018/11/27
```

Currently, to achieve this, I have an incredibly cumbersome implimentation. Here's my Excel writer class

**xlwriter.py**

```
class XLWriter:

def __init__(self, file):

    self.workbook = load_workbook(file)
    self.worksheet = self.workbook['Sheet1']
    self.file = file

def write_true(self, row):

    index = 0
    # function name, declare test passed, date
    values = [inspect.stack()[1][3], True, datetime.date)]
    # column numbers of above
    columns = [4, 6, 8]

    while index < 2:
        cell = self.worksheet.cell(row=row, column=columns[index])
        cell.value = values[index]
        index += 1

def write_true(self, row):

    index = 0
    # function name, declare test passed, date
    values = [inspect.stack()[1][3], False, datetime.date)]
    # column numbers of above
    columns = [4, 6, 8]

    while index < 2:
        cell = self.worksheet.cell(row=row, column=columns[index])
        cell.value = values[index]
        index += 1
```

And an example assertation from a test

**test.py**

```
try:
    self.assertEqual(url, url)
    xl.write_true(14)
    xl.save()
except:
    xl.write_false(14)
    xl.save()
```

This is not scalable. I was thinking a quick fix would be to return a `True` or `False` bool dependent on whether or not the test was successful, but I don't see a function for that behaviour in the unittest docs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer - **No.**

Long answer - **No.** But.. There are ways around the problem.

---

To re-vist the problem three months later, what do we actually plan to achieve?

We want to do the following

1. Run a unittest
2. Tell our database the test ran successfully

There is no need to return anything from the test itself in this case. Rather than *returning* a boolean, we can instead *send* a notification to `xlwriter.px` with the information it needs.

Before we do that, we need to rewrite `xlwriter.py`. Since creating this script, I've ported the database to SQLite.

**Manager.py**

```
import sqlite3
import datetime
import os

class Manager:
    def write_results_true(self, test):
        connection = sqlite3.connect(os.path.abspath('path'))
        connection.execute('UPDATE Details '
                           'SET Passed'
                           '= "True"'
                           'WHERE Name = "' + test + '";')
        connection.commit()
        connection.close()

    def write_results_false(self, test):
        connection = sqlite3.connect(os.path.abspath('path'))
        connection.execute('UPDATE Details '
                           'SET Passed'
                           '= "False"'
                           'WHERE Name = "' + test + '";')
        connection.commit()
        connection.close()
```

We've simplified the manager class, and now, to write to our database it's simple.

**test.py**

```
    def test_sample_test(self):
        """
        A sample test
        """
        a = 1

        if a == 1:
            m.write_results_true(stack()[0].function)
            self.assertEqual(a, 1)
        else:
            m.write_results_false(stack()[0].function)
            # A comment on why the test has failed
            self.fail('a does not equals 1')
```